# Reading csv in jupyter notebook is not working

Tags: python, csv, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I tried to run the following code in jupyter notebook to read csv file.

```
    import csv as csv
    with open('02_homework_dataset.csv') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            print(row[0])
```

I always get this error and I do not understand it:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-6877c6dff8f7> in <module>()
      4         reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
      5         for row in reader:
----> 6             print(row[0])

TypeError: print() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Does anyone has clue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `print` has not been redefined somewhere else in the code.

Comment: In the end, I figured out that the problem was with the kernel. When I restarted the kernel it helped.